# Outer join in ActiveRecord for complicated join

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join

I have a query that looks like this:

```
Flight.joins(:airline, 
             flight_legs:[:departure_airport,:arrival_airport,
                aircraft:[aircraft_model:[:aircraft_make]]]).where('flights.user_id = ?',@current_user.id).order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")
```

Kinda big, yeah. Problem that I'm getting here is that because it's an INNER JOIN, the rows returned do not include those which don't have all of the listed joins.

Is there an easy way to get all of the listed rows, and allow me to still query the individual linked tables with where queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will solve your problem

```
Flight.joins("LEFT JOIN airlines ON airlines.id=flights.airline_id LEFT JOIN flight_legs ON flight_legs.id= flights.flight_leg_id LEFT JOIN departure_airports ON flight_legs.departure_airport_id=departure_airport_id LEFT JOIN arrival_airports ON arrival_airports.id=flight_legs.arriavak_airport_id LEFT JOIN aircrafts ON flights.aircraft_id=aircrafts.id LEFT JOIN aircraft_models ON aircraft_model.id=aircrafts.aircraft_model_id LEFT JOIN aircraft_makes ON aircraft_makes.id=aircraft_model.aircraft_make_id").where('flights.user_id = ?',@current_user.id).order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")
```